# d3 timeline scaling according to svg width

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to get a draggable timeline working in d3, with the requirement that if the width of the svg element is increased and the page reloaded, the ticks on the timebar have the same distance between them, but the amount of time that the timeline represents is reduced.

My current ticks definition is as follows

`var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").ticks(d3.time.hour, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));`

There is an example here; You can see problem if the width is changed to 600, instead of representing twice as much time, instead the ticks are twice as far apart.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnkN6/259/

Comment: You'll have to compute and set the tick values explicitly for that using `.tickValues()`.